# てほしい particle usage

Tags: grammar

> 管理に適切な分家筋を選んでほしい。

I understand the meaning, but not the particle used.

> 貴方に英語を教えて欲しい

に is used to show the one who does the action you want him to.
を is used to show what you want to have done.

Why is this sentence like this?

Edit.
Posted the whole context

> 補足。
>   七夜の血筋は、ある種殺人鬼を輩出する一族である。
>   もしあの養子が生き残ってしまった場合、命を共有して繋がっているシキに悪影響を及ぼすだろう。
>   せっかく理性を取り戻したシキが、七夜の養子に引きずられて『殺人鬼』になってしまう可能性も否定できない。
>
> そのような事態が起きないよう、養子は目の届く範囲で飼わなければならない。
>   だが遠野の屋敷に近づける事も許されない。
>   管理に適切な分家筋を選んでほしい。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 管理{かんり}に適切{てきせつ}な分家筋{ぶんけすじ}を選{えら}んでほしい。

This sentence will be translated as ''I want you to select a ''分家筋{ぶんけすじ}'' that is appropriate to manage it.

Only glancing at the sentence, you cannot find out the real meaning. It's necessary to guess it from the context or from every meaning of the words.

I will give an example as follows.

> 彼{かれ}に英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてほしい。

This sentence can be translated as two ways.

> **A**.   I want him to teach someone English.
>
> **A'**  （彼女{かのじょ}が私{わたし}に英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてくれると言{い}っているけれど、私{わたし}は）彼{かれ}に英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてほしい。
>
> **B**.   I want you to teach him English.
>
> **B'**. （あなたは英語{えいご}を教{おし}えるのがうまいから、あなたが）彼{かれ}に英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてほしい。

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this, but he problem of my sentence arises from the fact that this person has 2 personalities and there is no one else besides him who can make the choice since he is the head of the family and is alone.

I tought he might be referring to his other personality and since I was not sure I looked up the fantranslation that says:
I should have him raised by an appropriate branch of the family