# に vs. が in the ~てほしい construction

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-が

I know there are already a few questions about this topic on this website, however none of them seemed to really help me with the issue.

The ~てほしい contruction is used to express that someone wants someone/something else to do something. Now, my problem is with the particle that is used to mark the person/thing that is supposed to carry out the desired action: Should it be が or に, or can it be both?

In most examples I saw, に was used. For example:

> あなたに幸せになってほしい。

But occasionally, there were also examples with が. So I tried to think about a solution, and I came up with the idea that maybe が was only used to avoid misunderstandings, such as in the following example provided by Toshihiko in the answer to the question [てほしい particle usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bb%e3%81%97%e3%81%84-particle-usage):

> 私はあなたが彼に英語を教えてほしい。
>   I want you to teach him English.

But then I found another example sentence:

> 冬が早く来て欲しい。
>   I want winter to come soon.

Here, the が doesn't seem to be used to avoid any misunderstandings because the sentence is simple enough as it is.

So after all, what determines if you should use が or に to mark the person or thing that should carry out the action when using the ~てほしい construction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

が is emphasizing the noun before it than に.

あなたに幸せになってほしい
I want you to be happy.

あなたが幸せになってほしい
I want **YOU** to be happy.
It's not common and must be some important meaning on 'you'. More like dialogue in a movie.

Although I feel your second example is simply wrong. In this case we should use に. Even it has to be "you" who teach him English.

Comment: What would be the purpose of emphasizing 冬 in 冬が早く来て欲しい。?

Comment: Totally depends on a context, but for me I can feel that a person awaiting winter who said that. It's very difficult which would be used, even a writer, I guess.

Comment: @Darius, あ～確かに 「冬**が**早く来てほしい」は言いそうですけど、「冬**に**早く来て欲しい。」って言いませんよね・・なんででしょうね。。

Comment: I think 〜に probably requires some agency of the thing bring marked.

Comment: If it's a conversation, saying 「私は冬に早く来てほしい」 as an answer to someone's 「夏が早く来てほしい」 is quite normal, rather fluent I feel. interesting.

Comment: ^ 「夏**が**早く来てほしい」-- 「私は冬**に**早く来てほしい」← Then, it means that (冬)に is more emphasized than (夏)が, no?

Comment: Maybe yes, but in this case it's just saying "I prefer 冬 unlike you prefer 夏", not particularly emphasizing 冬 itself I guess. But, answering 「私は冬が早く来てほしい」 is also not wrong at all, it's interesting...

Answer (score 4):

### Kimi Tanaka's answer

First I want to cite Kimi Tanaka's answer and he/she says that:

> > 冬が早く来て欲しい
>
> This is not simply a request, but you are hoping something to happen. 〜が...て欲しい does not supply a particular instruction though, it could be a request in a roundabout way. In this case, the winter does not listen to your request. So, 冬に早く来て欲しい is strange.

I agree to this explanation.

For general, `XがYする` means X does Y for X's own demand. And `ZがXにYをさせる` means Z makes X to do Y **for Z's demand**.

So like

> 冬が来る。 ("Winter comes.")

sounds natural while

> 冬に早く来て欲しい。

is strange because the winter comes no matter if you wish it to come earlier.

### ゆるキャン's answer

ゆるキャン showed a good point and I agree to it.

### Summary

I don't have no reference but I think:

1. `が` has emphasizing effect, but can easily be strange if you mention to things you can't control / ask to do something
2. `には` has almost same effect of `に`. In some cases `には` is effective to emphasize what you mention to.

Some examples here.

> あなたに幸せになってほしい。 (Sounds natural)
>
> あなたが幸せになってほしい。 (Sounds a bit strange but not invalid. It sounds like it emphasizes あなた)
>
> あなたには幸せになってほしい。(Sounds way natural, and the speaker is not hoping another person's happiness but yours. Better emphasis than `が`.)
>
> 彼にこの仕事をやってほしい (Natural. It means "I want him to do this job")
>
> 彼がこの仕事をやってほしい (Sounds wrong / invalid)
>
> 彼にはこの仕事をやってほしい (Natural, almost equivalent to `に` version)
>
> あの犬に元気になってほしい (Natural. It means "I hope that dog gets better.")
>
> あの犬が元気になってほしい (Very strange, almost invalid)
>
> あの犬には元気になってほしい (Natural, and perhaps **more** natural than `に` version)

`あなたに彼に英語を教えてほしい` has another object `彼に` in it and it causes difference to `が`, `に`, `には` usages.

> あなたに彼に英語を教えてほしい (A bit strange, it's because the same postpositional particle `に` occurs multiple times. It should be avoided.)
>
> あなたが彼に英語を教えてほしい (Natural. There may be other people who can teach English but the speaker wishes YOU to teach him English.)
>
> あなたには彼に英語を教えてほしい (Natural. The speaker assigns you to teach him English. It's unclear that there are more people who can teach English.)

`に` and `には` has similar usage so they can be used to avoid the same postpositional particle to appear multiple times in one sentence.

Comment: Since `あの犬に元気になってほしい` is natural while `冬に早く来て欲しい` is not because I have no control over Winter coming, does the former imply I'm doing/want to do something about it?

Also, why is `あなたが幸せになってほしい` right, and `彼がこの仕事をやってほしい` wrong? In both cases I can do something about it, so I'm not sure what's the difference.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure but in my feeling `に` is frequently used to human and animals compared to other inanimate things. 2. Hard to explain but `彼がこの仕事をやってほしい` is so strange.. anyway `あなたが幸せになってほしい` is not impossible but strange. I don't say like this.

Answer (score 2):

> あなたに幸せになってほしい。

This sentence implies encouraging the listener when the speaker will help the partner need to be happy.

In a similar way, next sentence is also kind of encouragement.

> 私はあなた**が**彼に英語を教えてほしい。 I request/ask **you** to teach English.

This is the mix of emphatic "が" to specify the person and requesting/asking them to.

While,

> 冬が早く来て欲しい。I expect/look forward winter to coming soon.

This is not simply a request, but you are hoping something to happen. 〜が...て欲しい does not supply a particular instruction though, it could be a request in a roundabout way. In this case, the winter does not listen to your request. So, 冬に早く来て欲しい is strange.

> ex) 電気が早く通ってほしい。

Whether the electricity will immediately run during blackout/power outage is not really under your control. Saying so might indirectly be telling local governments/electric power companies to react on soon though.